# Question terminée par « s'il vous plaît ». Quelle origine?

Tags: questions, régionalismes, politesse

J'ai croisé à quelques reprises des gens qui utilisaient l'expression « s'il vous plaît » à la fin d'une phrase contenant une question. Par exemple : « est-ce que ça va s'il vous plaît ? »

Je crois qu'il s'agissait de gens du Moyen-Orient ou peut-être d'Afrique du nord. D'après leur accent, je crois qu'ils étaient Arabes.

De quelle langue et de quelle nationalité cette grammaire vient-elle et pourquoi forment-ils leur phrase ainsi ?

Comment: As far as grammar goes, the questions you can propose can only concern 1) French grammar or 2) the grammar of a foreign language if those questions are a matter of interest in the translation of a **word or phrase** from that foreign language into French; I should add that the foreign languages that are discussed on the count of their grammar according to this tacit rule are in the number of one, English. Your question is about customs; in France there is no such custom or if it exists in France it has to be in in a very small locality known to almost nobody.

Comment: This is not really about grammar but about an unusually high level of politeness.

Answer (score 1):

Il est possible qu'elle vienne de l'arabe où on dit [*min fadhlik*](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/1386877) après des questions comme celle-ci alors que ce serait incongru de l'ajouter en anglais.

Answer (score 1):

Parfois, il ne s'agit plus de question mais plutôt d'une demande, et parfois aussi c'est une sorte de respect mais dans la majorité de cas, c'est à cause de l'accent car on trouve souvent le terme *s'il vous plait* en Afrique du nord.

Comment: Et dans quel contexte est-il utilisé en Afrique du Nord?

Comment: @Pier-YvesLessard Génerallement cette formule de politesse est utilisée suite à une demande.